# Undefined variable $categories

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my code, I'm very new to this, so I'm having trouble finding the problem.

I want my categories to be displayed, so I can select one and assign it to the keyword, the site tells me that my categories are not defined

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $motsCles = Mot_Cles::all();
        $categories = Categories::all(); 

        
        $request->validate([
            'mot' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);


        
        $motCle = Mot_cles::create([
            'mot' => $request->input('mot'),
        ]);

        $category = Categories::find($request->category);
        $motCle->categories()->attach($category);



        return view('Mots_Cles', compact('categories'));
        return view('Mots_Cles', compact('motsCles'));

    
        event(new Registered($motCle));
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

I tried to define the categories but everything seems to be fine, I wonder if it has something to do with the routes

Comment: 3 -return? After the first one, the function will stop

Comment: Please post the _complete_ error message (and maybe highlight the line on which it occurs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have 3 return, only the first return fill be executed (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php). You can use multiple parameters in `compact()` function, sou you can maybe try this : `return view('Mots_Cles', compact('categories', 'motsCles'));`. I'm not totally sure to understand what you want to display, but it seems you are using Laravel, you can use `dd();` function to learn what append in your variable and maybe find a solution or share what append to us.
To help you to learn best practice in Laravel, I recommand you to read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x) and you can check [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) for more consistent example

Comment: Wouldn't `$categories` be defined if `return view('Mots_Cles', compact('categories'));` triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You use Model name wrong so first check the model name and second not use two return view-

```
$motsCles = Mot_Cles::all();
$categories = Categories::all(); 
$request->validate([
    'mot' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);

$motCle = Mot_Cles::create([
    'mot' => $request->mot,
]);

$category = Categories::find($request->category);
$motCle->categories()->attach($category);
event(new Registered($motCle));
if(event(new Registered($motCle));){
    return redirect('/home');
}else{
    return view('Mots_Cles', compact(['categories','motsCles']));
}
```

Comment: That would trigger `event(new Registered($motCle))` twice!!?!

Comment: "_You use Model name wrong_" How so? What would be the correct way?

Comment: I think you use table name not a model name

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing your function to the code below:

Please also see the comments i have added for more information throughout the function :)

```
public function store(Request $request) {

// Recommended :: move Validation to its own request
$request->validate([
    'mot' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);

$category = Categories::find($request->category);
$motCle = Mot_cles::create($request->validated());
$motCle->categories()->attach($category);

event(new Registered($motCle));

// Question :: Do you want it to return to the route service provider route or a defined route?

// Defined
return redirect()->route('mots_cles', [
    'categories' => Categories::all(),
    'motsCles' => Mot_Cles::all(),
]);


// Route service provider route

/*
 *  If you do this route you will need to make sure the view is being pass the variables as well,
 *  this will be done via a view composer or the controller the route is using.
 */

return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```